# Why `async` doesn't inherit SupervisorJob if called directly inside the coroutine block?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Given the code snippets below:

Snippet [1]

```
val job = SupervisorJob()
val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO + job)
scope.launch {
   try {
     scope.async {
       throw RuntimeException("Oops!")
     }.await()
   } catch(e: Exception) {
    // Handle exception
   }
}
```

and Snippet [2]

```
val job = SupervisorJob()
val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO + job)
scope.launch {
   try {
     async {
       throw RuntimeException("Oops!")
     }.await()
   } catch(e: Exception) {
    // Handle exception
   }
}
```

The first one works, and second snippet crashes. The general explanation is that in the first case, `async` inherit the `SupervisorJob` from `scope`, and in the second case no.

My question is, if `async` is an extension function of `CoroutineScope`, why in the second case (which crashes) it doesn't inherit the `SupervisorJob` in the same way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first snippet, because you explicitly override the scope established by the `launch` builder, there is no parent-child relationship between it and the `async` block you have inside it.

This is an equivalent way to write the first snippet:

```
val deferred = scope.async {
    throw RuntimeException()
}

scope.launch {
    try {
        deferred.await()
    } catch(e: Exception) {
    }
}
```

The `async` coroutine fails with an exception. Its parent is a `SupervisorJob`, which ignores the failure. The `launch` coroutine calls `Deferred.await()`, which throws an exception. You catch the exception and nothing fails.

Your second snippet can be rewritten as follows:

```
scope.launch {
    val innerScope = this

    innerScope.async {
        throw RuntimeException()
    }
}
```

Here you can see explicitly which scope the `async` block inherits. It is not the top-level one with `SupervisorJob`, but the inner one that `launch` created. When the `async` coroutine fails, the parent job reacts to it by first cancelling all the other children (none in this case) and then itself. The `deferred.await()` statement makes no difference here, which is why I removed it. The `launch` coroutine will automatically wait for all the child coroutines to complete anyway.

Comment: In the second snippet, in the `async` scope, who's the parent going to be?

Comment: Parent is the Job associated with the `launch`ed coroutine.

Answer (score 2):

`launch` creates a new Job, and propagates that into the `CoroutineScope` that the block receives.  In the second snippet, the `async` job is a child of the `launch` Job, and the `launch` job is cancelled when its child fails.

In the first snippet, the `async` job is a child of the `SupervisorJob` you made, which is not cancelled when its child fails.  The `launch` job in this case has no children.  It just catches the exception and completes.

Answer (score 0):

As I see, newer versions of coroutines both of your snippets will work. Just wrap the function `await()` with try/catch block.